# Additional elements to URLS?

Tags: php, tag-it

I'm not sure what the terminology is, but basically I have a site that uses the "tag-it" system, currently you can click on the tags and it takes the user to

```
topics.php?tags=example
```

My question is what sort of scripting or coding would be required to be able to add additional links?

```
topics.php?tags=example&tags=example2
```

or

```
topics.php?tags=example+example2
```

Here is the code in how my site is linked to tags.

```
header("Location: topics.php?tags={$t}");
```

or

```
<a href="topics.php?tags=<?php echo $fetch_name->tags; ?>"><?php echo strtolower($fetch_name->tags);?></a>
```

Thanks for any hints or tips.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot really pass tags two times as a GET parameter although you can pass it as an array

```
topics.php?tags[]=example&tags[]=example2
```

Assuming this is what you want try

```
$string = "topics.php?";
foreach($tags as $t)
{
    $string .= "tag[]=$t&";
}
$string = substr($string, 0, -1);
```

We iterate through the array concatenating value to our $string. The last line removes an extra & symbol that will appear after the last iteration

There is also another option that looks a bit more dirty but might be better depending on your needs

```
$string = "topics.php?tag[]=" . implode($tags, "&tag[]=");
```

**Note** Just make sure the tags array is not empty

Comment: That's what i was going to post

Comment: The "correct" way to build such a URL query string is to use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php): `http_build_query( array( 'tags' => array( 'example-tag-1', 'example-tag-2' ) ) );`

Comment: Thanks for the handy function, shame i've never encountered it before

Answer (score 0):

> `topics.php?tags=example&tags=example2`
>   will break in the back end;

you have to assign the data to one variable:

`topics.php?tags=example+example2`

looks good you can access it in the back end [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it by the `+` sign:

```
//toplics.php
<?php
    ...
    $tags = urlencode($_GET['tags']);
    $tags_arr = explode('+', $tags); // array of all tags

    $current_tags = ""; //make this accessible in the view;
    if($tags){
         $current_tags = $tags ."+"; 
    }
   //show your data
?>
```

Edit:
you can create the fron-end tags:

```
<a href="topics.php?tags=<?php echo $current_tags ;?>horror">
    horror
</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the plus sign is a good choice, if I recall correctly it's a special url character.

Comment: Yes, the plus sign is a special url character for blankspace :)

Comment: Thanks for your post, I already have it currently set up with the $_GET['tags'] part, my only confussion is making it so if I have

movie    horror

as tags, i can be on "movie" and then click on "horror" and it add it to the URL.

I used + as an example as i've seen SO use that system.

Comment: + sign is good because it makes the url more readable for the current scenario, you can always decode it in the back end.